# Pugh's definition of derivatives using limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

According to Pugh's real analysis textbook, the function $f:(a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x$ if

$$
\lim _{t \rightarrow x} \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}=L
$$

which Pugh then translates to $\forall \epsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta > 0 \; 0 < |t-x| < \delta \implies |\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-L| < \epsilon$

But I don't think that matches - according to his definition of limits throughout the book, the implication should instead look like $|t-x| < \delta \implies |\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-L| < \epsilon$. (I understand why it should be greater than 0, I'm just pointing out an inconsistency in notation).

Is there a hidden condition for the domain of t (below the limit) in this definition that Pugh is not mentioning? How is it usually defined? (is the usual convention then to define derivatives as $\lim_{t \to x, t \neq x} \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}$, or something else?) (or does Pugh address these later in the book?)

Comment: Really?  Write out for us his definition of limit verbatim as it appears in the text.

Comment: Can you tell us what L stands for?  Is it a number? A function? Or something else?

Comment: This looks like a literal translation of the usual definition of $\lim_{t \to x}$, i.e. the restriction that $|x - t|$ not be $0$ (i.e. that $t \neq x$) is very much part of the usual definition of the limit. Although I have no idea what might be elsewhere in that book

Comment: Are you confusing limit with his definition of continuity?

Comment: Every definition of limit excludes evaluation at the point approached by the variable. Not just derivatives.

Comment: I realize I was confused - I sifted through Pugh's textbook and it seems like he never explicitly provides the definition of function limits (except indirectly, in his definition of continuous functions, in which he does not restrict the implication to be greater than zero). But it looks like the Wikipedia does define function limits in that way, so I think that resolves it. I was confused because I come from Terry Tao's Analysis textbook which defines limits in yet another way.

Comment: I just pulled the book down:  he never even defines limit rigorously, and they only appear when discussing continuity, where $|t-x| < \delta$ is fully appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, so from now on I'll follow the convention there and just go with the >0 definition.

Comment: Another definition that sidesteps the whole limit silliness is the fresh hay derivative https://nhigham.com/2020/06/23/what-is-a-frechet-derivative/

Comment: Does it really avoid limits if the definition has a little-$o$ in it?

Comment: @Randall Yes, it avoids the whole issue of $t \neq x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a real-valued function where $X\subseteq\textbf{R}$. If $x_{0}\in X$ is also *an accumulation point*, we define the derivative of $f$ at $x_{0}\in X$ as the real number $L$ (if it exists) if and only if
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists\delta_{\varepsilon} > 0)(\forall x\in X)(0 < |x - x_{0}| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow \left|\frac{f(x) - f(x_{0})}{x - x_{0}} - L\right| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}
As it can be observed, we cannot consider $x = x_{0}$ (otherwise the denominator would be zero).

That is why we have to consider $0 < |x - x_{0}| < \delta_{\varepsilon}$.

Nonetheless, there is no harm at doing so: since $x_{0}$ is also an accumulation point, we can study the behavior of the quotient as near to $x_{0}$ as one pleases.

Comment: Thanks, is the reason why $x_0$ must be an accumulation point (i.e. a point where $\forall r>0$, the r-ball around $x_0$ contains infinite points in X) because that's equivalent to each neighborhood of $x_0$ containing at least one point of $X$ other than itself (By Theorem 52), hence allowing there to at least be one $x$ satisfying $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta$?

Comment: That's exactly the point !

Comment: Nice! Now I am no longer confused :)

Comment: @user1143399 I am glad to help :)